# why is here "Namen" instead of "Name"

Tags: grammar, translation, english-to-german

99 Prozent der Anwälte geben dem Rest einen schlechten Namen.
99 percent of lawyers give the rest a bad name.

Edit: Shouldn't it be "einen schlechten Name", if this is accusative. Why is -n added?

Comment: Because that’s the [accusative of *Name*](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Name) ? Please give details of what you do not understand.

Answer (score 8):

*Name* belongs to [an inflection class that has *n* in almost every ending](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-N/FKlassen/Klasse-ens-en1.html).

Note, however, that one would rather say *Ruf* in your example.