# Suffix "-n" in end of accusative "Namen"

Tags: accusative

> Heute tragen viele Straßen seinen Namen.

What is the *-n* in end of *Namen*.
Of course, it's not plural because he has just one name.

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8472

Comment: Since the answer is in the title, I do not understand the question.

Answer (score 3):

*Namen* is the accusative form of *Name*. You can determine the case of an objective by asking following questions:

- Wer oder was? Nominativ
- Wen oder was? Akkusativ
- Wem oder was? Dativ
- Wessen oder was? Genitiv

So, in this case you ask "Wen oder was trägt die Straße?" — "Seinen Namen".

The definite article is also dependent on the case.

- Nominativ: sein
- Akkusativ: seinen
- Dativ: seinem
- Genitiv: seines

Comment: Using these question to determine which case should has been used is pretty pointless for a non-native learner of German ;)

Comment: @Gerhard I don't know that, this is what I was taught in school xD but with the second method you can determine the case of the objects in a given sentence.

Comment: Yes, me too. And it works nicely for a native German speaker to identify the cases in a sentence, because you know which question "sounds" correct. A non-native speaker does not have this feeling, at least not for quite a while.

Comment: Thank you @armin , but as Gehraed said , theese questions can't help non-native students :) , thank you again

Comment: @a_barsa well, there nothing more than telling you that tragen requires the abusive.

Comment: Another question , forgive me bjt I'm learning alone and that's not easy,  even if it's accusative , I didn't learn that also the noun change if it was as avvusativ. I mean we say (ich habe einen Kurs) we don't say (ich habe einen Kursn) is this something special with ( Name) ? -@Armin

Comment: @a_barsa Please don’t ask follow-up questions in comments. Instead, [edit the original question](/posts/27629/edit) if the new one is about a detail or [ask a new question](/questions/ask).

Comment: @a_barsa this question is also answered in the linked question in the comments of your question

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the above reply, there are different cases for the the substantives. In this case it is `Wen oder Was?` the `Akkusativ` case, which results in `sein Name` becoming `seinen Namen`.

It is just a rule of German grammar and might not make any sense to you if you are not familiar with German grammar in general.