# Why is it "in meinem Herzen"?

Tags: grammar, possessive-pronoun

I came across an amazing aria called "Der Hölle Rache kocht in meinem Herzen". It is sung by the Queen of the Night in *The Magic Flute* (*Die Zauberflöte*), an opera by Mozart.

I don't understand why the phrase "in meinem Herzen" is used here.

- Since *Herzen* is the plural form of *das Herz*, is it implying that the Queen of the Night has multiple hearts?
- Additionally, I'm fairly confident that this phrase is in the Dativ case. If so, why is *meinem* used instead of *meinen*?

edit: here's what I thought: this phrase is Dativ and *Herzen* indicates plural, so it is similar to "mit meinen Kindern". I didn't see why "meinem" is used instead, but that now I know that *Herzen* is singular Dativ, the phrase makes more sense. Thanks!

PS: I'm a beginner in learning German. I hope that this question doesn't sound too strange.

Comment: I don't have time to write an answer, now, but it is explained here in German: http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/beugung-des-substantivs-herz

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8472/why-is-here-namen-instead-of-name, https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/28908/schwache-nomen-n-deklination

Comment: "das Herz" has a special declention. Either you look it up in the dictionary or you google for it (Deklination von Herz)  http://kommunikationsabc.de/2014/02/05/die-schwierige-deklination-des-wortes-herz/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Herzen* is not only the plural (in all cases), but the dative singular form, too. It belongs to a group of nouns called “weak”; see, e.g., [German for English speakers](http://germanforenglishspeakers.com/nouns/weak-nouns-the-n-declension/) or [canoonet](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-N/FKlassen/Klasse-ens-en1.html?lang=en).

Comment: So would it be wrong to say "in meinem Herz" in this context? What about if Herz was being used in a less metaphorical way, such as describing a medical condition related to the heart, would "in meinem Herzen" still be used?

Comment: Thanks for the link. Does this mean that the phase is Genitiv? I've not learnt of this case yet

Comment: @Jessica *in meinem Herz* is also correct, the longer form *Herzen* is somewhat old-fashioned and poetic. In a medical context, I'd be surprised to hear *Herzen* instead of *Herz*.

Comment: @Chieron: [Normale Flussmuster am fetalen Herzen](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-20938-3_20) (2012), [Myokardrevaskularisation bei hochgradig eingeschränkter linksventrikulärer Funktion](http://edoc.hu-berlin.de/habilitationen/hausmann-harald-2004-02-26/PDF/Hausmann.pdf) (2004; „beim chronisch ischämischen Herzen des Menschen“, „welches normalerweise im Herzen nur in (…) gefunden wird“, „Myokardszintigraphie am gesunden Herzen“ usw.), [Herzchirurgie: Die Eingriffe am Herzen und an den herznahen Gefäßen](https://books.google.de/books?id=x68kBAAAQBAJ) (2010), …

Comment: @Chieron, I disagree. I would always say "Herzen".

Comment: @Jessica: In your case it's correct to use either `Herz` or `Herzen`, but don't think this is a general option. Cases like `In meinem Schmerzen konnte ich nicht arbeiten.` or `In meinem Scherzen kommt das Wort »Kind« vor.` are false, here you must use `Schmerz` and `Scherz`.

Comment: @Pollitzer: Why are you speaking about unrelated other words now? (Even if they happen to rhyme with _Herz_.)

Comment: @chirlu point taken. I'd still avoid it except when speaking of the metaphorical heart (feelings). Using it for the organ and heart-shapes sounds old-fashioned to me, at least.

Comment: @chirlu: Because a German-learner may think all nouns ending with »erz« are treated the same way.

Answer (score 3):

*Herzen* is singular dative. There is the alternative form *Herz* ([Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Herz), [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Herz)), but dictionaries attribute this mainly to [medical use](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Herzen) (also Duden above).

And since it is singular and dative, the *meinem* should not be surprising any more.

Comment: I've edited the question! Hopefully I explained my dilemma better this time.      Thank you for the links.

Comment: @Jessica, ah, I see.